# How to add ordinal suffix to date form select in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I would like to add ordinals to the dates in a zend 2 dateselect form element.

In Zend 1 I could do something like

```
$form->get('dob'), Zend_Date::DAY_SUFFIX
```

I know I should use PHP 5's DateTime class but I can't seem to get it working.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are we talking about $d = new \DateTime (); echo $d->format ("dS M Y");?

Comment: Something along those lines akond. I'm just not sure how to apply it to the 'dateselect'  element.